# Google cookies or sessions

Tags: session, cookies, google-account

Is possible to detect Google cookies and sessions from browser to warn user that logout from his account?
I need detect it by my site.(PHP or JavaScript)

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.cookie`to get current cookies. You can't access outside cookies.